Efficiently generate user history with negative sampling for recommendation system using Polars API
I’m working on a recommendation system, and I need to efficiently generate user history with negative sampling using the Polars API. I have two datasets:

User-Article Interactions:
•   This dataset contains the user_id and the article_id of articles that the user has read.
Example:

import polars as pl
    
df_user_articles = pl.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'article_id': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]
})

This dataset contains all article_id and their corresponding text data.
df_articles = pl.DataFrame({
    'article_id': list(range(100, 200)),  # example article IDs
    'text': ['text'] * 100
})

For each user_id, I want to:

Create a history of articles they’ve read, with a length between 5 and 20.
Generate candidates for each user by selecting some articles they’ve read (positive samples) and some they haven’t (negative samples). The candidates should be labeled:

-1 for articles the user has read.
-0 for articles the user hasn’t read.



Output format:
I want the output as a DataFrame with the following columns:

user_id: The user ID.
user_history: A list of article IDs the user has read.
candidates: A list of candidate article IDs, each labeled with -1 or -0.




user_id
user_history
candidates




1
['101', '102']
['101-1', '102-1', '103-0']


2
['103', '104', '105']
['103-1', '104-1', '105-1', '106-0']



How can I efficiently achieve this using the Polars API, avoiding apply and ensuring that the solution scales well with large datasets?
To optimize for efficiency, we don’t need to check if the article IDs have been read by the user during candidate generation.
I have a solution but it not keep the category type of "article_id"
matrix_size = users_df.shape[0]

num_candidates = 5

index_matrix = np.random.randint(0, articles_df.shape[0], size=(matrix_size, num_candidates))

index_matrix
users_df.with_columns(
    candidates=articles_df['article_id'].to_numpy()[:,np.newaxis][index_matrix].reshape(matrix_size, num_candidates)
    )


Why does user_id=2 get 106? Is it because it is in another user_history? Or is it just a sample from all df_articles they have not read?

Because he haven't read it and its a negative sample

Maybe not the most simple way to do it, but if you need random amount of negative candidates, you can do something like this:
def sample(x):
    user_history = x["user_history"]
    r = x["literal"]
    return (
        df_articles
        .filter(~pl.col.article_id.is_in(user_history))
        .sample(r)
        .select(pl.col.article_id.cast(pl.String) + "-0")
        .to_series()
    )

df = (
    df_user_articles
    .group_by("user_id")
    .agg(
        user_history = "article_id",
        candidates = pl.col("article_id").cast(pl.String) + "-1"
    )
)

candidates_num = 2

df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.col.candidates,
        pl.struct([
            np.random.randint(1, candidates_num, df.height),
            pl.col.user_history
        ])
        .map_elements(sample, return_dtype = pl.List(pl.String))
    ).alias("candidates")
)

┌─────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ user_id ┆ user_history      ┆ candidates                    │
│ ---     ┆ ---               ┆ ---                           │
│ i64     ┆ list[i64]         ┆ list[str]                     │
╞═════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ [101, 102]        ┆ ["101-1", "102-1", … "164-0"] │
│ 4       ┆ [107, 108, … 110] ┆ ["107-1", "108-1", … "115-0"] │
│ 3       ┆ [106]             ┆ ["106-1", "193-0", "152-0"]   │
│ 2       ┆ [103, 104, 105]   ┆ ["103-1", "104-1", … "164-0"] │
└─────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘

There's another solution which avoids map_elements, but it might be also not really performant cause it requires to cross join list of users and list of articles.
df_user_history = (
    df_user_articles
    .group_by("user_id")
    .agg(user_history = pl.col.article_id)
)

num_candidates = 5

df = (
    df_user_history
    .join(df_articles, how="cross")
    .group_by("user_id")
    .agg(
        candidates = pl.col.article_id.sample(num_candidates).unique()
    ).with_columns(
        pl.col.candidates.list.head(
            pl.int_range(1, num_candidates).shuffle().sample(pl.len(), with_replacement=True)
        )
    )
)

(
    df_user_history
    .join(df, on="user_id")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.candidates.list.set_difference(pl.col.user_history)
    )
    .with_columns(
        candidates = pl.concat([
            pl.col.user_history.list.explode().cast(pl.String) + "-0",
            pl.col.candidates.list.explode().cast(pl.String) + "-1"
        ]).implode().over("user_id")
    )
)


I am trying to avoid map_elements, I have millions of rows

Millions of rows in which dataframe?

df_users_articles

And what about total number of articles - df_articles?

there are ~1.3m

I have updated the question with a solution, but it's not memory effcient

I think if you use pl.int_range(1, 5).shuffle() instead of numpy's randint - LazyFrames could be used. (and potentially .collect(streaming=True))

@jqurious thanks, I've updated the answer, I've added sample() on top of shuffle() to create a column with random integer for each user.

@roman - the cross join is problemtic to large datasets, ComputeError: cross joins would produce more rows than fits into 2^32

well it depends on the fine details of the task. For example, you can pre-sample the dataframe of articles - take 1000 (or 5 * number of users or whatever) random articles which are going to be assigned to the users later. So then cross join is not going to increase the size so much.
I honestly only see 2 option - either cross join with (reduced) frame of articles and then sample at once via groupby (merge join), or you sample for each row from the whole dataframe, but that means map_elements() and sampling through 1.3m rows for every user (nested loops)
